# Playing videos in succession with MediaElement + Storyboard

Tags: c#, winforms, video, storyboard, mediaelement

I have a timeline of video files that were recorded in succession.  I need to play them in my application in the same order.

1. I already know the relative start time and duration of each video.
2. The next video may not have started recording until several seconds, minutes, or even hours after the previous video stopped recording.
3. I need some sort of position changed notification so that I can sync other UI elements to the video position (e.g. graphs).
4. During sections where no video was recorded the video window will show a blank screen.
5. Unfortunately I'm stuck using WinForms for now, but I am embedding a `MediaElement` in an `ElementHost`.

It seems that a `MediaTimeline` + `Storyboard` combination would suit my needs well. The `Storyboard` provides a `CurrentTimeInvalidated` event that satisfies condition 3. As for conditions 1 and 2, I believe I can create a `MediaTimeline` for each video and add each one of them as a child in the `Storyboard`. It seems that I have it partially working, but am having a few problems still.

With my current implementation, the storyboard plays from start to finish just fine. However, video only shows up for the last video added to the storyboard.

Here is some simplified pseudo-code for the video timeline player that I want to implement.

```
public class VideoTimelineEntry
{
    public Uri Uri;
    public TimeSpan RelativeStartTime;
    public TimeSpan Duration;
}

public class VideoTimelinePlayer : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    private MediaElement _mediaElement = ...; // Contained in ElementHost
    private Storyboard _storyboard = new Storyboard();

    public void LoadTimeline(IEnumerable<VideoTimelineEntry> entries)
    {
        foreach (VideoTimelineEntry entry in entries)
        {
            MediaTimeline mediaTimeline = new MediaTimeline
            {
                BeginTime = entry.RelativeStartTime,
                Duration  = new Duration(entry.Duration),
                Source    = entry.Uri
            };

            _storyboard.Children.Add(mediaTimeline);

            // I think this is my problem. How do I set the target
            // so that it is always playing the current video, and
            // not just the last one in my timeline?
            Storyboard.SetTarget(mediaTimeline, _mediaElement);
        }
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        _storyboard.Begin();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        _storyboard.Pause();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _storyboard.Stop();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you can only target 1 `MediaElement` per `MediaTimeline`. As a work-around, I am now creating a dedicated `MediaElement` for each `MediaTimeline`. This does not feel like a good solution in my opinion, but I can't think of a better way unless I wanted to deal with polling/timing and dynamically changing the video source. However, my whole reason for using a `Storyboard` was so that I could avoid doing that.

### Update 7/24/14

I've decided to post a very watered down example to improve this answer.

```cs
public void LoadTimeline(IEnumerable<MediaTimeline> mediaTimelines)
{
    // Check that none of the timelines overlap as specified by the
    // acceptance criteria.
    // e.g. timeline2.BeginTime < timeline1.BeginTime + timeline1.Duration.

    _storyboard.Children.Clear();

    foreach (MediaTimeline mediaTimeline in mediaTimelines)
    {
        _storyboard.Children.add(mediaTimeline);

        MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();

        // _grid is just an empty <Grid></Grid> in the xaml layer.
        _grid.Children.Add(mediaElement);

        // Each media timeline now targets a dedicated media element.
        Storyboard.SetTarget(mediaTimeline, mediaElement);

        // Bring the active media element to the top.
        mediaTimeline.CurrentStateInvalidated += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Panel.SetZIndex(mediaElement, int.MaxValue);
        };
    }
}
```